# Wiki example for Arnoldi iteration only works for real matrices?

Tags: python, matrix, wikipedia, complex-numbers

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration#The_Arnoldi_iteration) for the Arnoldi method provides a Python example that produces basis of the Krylov subspace of a matrix `A`. Supposedly, if `A` is Hermitian (i.e. if `A == A.conj().T`) then the Hessenberg matrix `h` generated by this algorithm is tridiagonal ([source](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859n-f16/Handouts/TrefethenBau/ArnoldiIteration-33.pdf)). However, when I use the Wikipedia code on a real-world Hermitian matrix, the Hessenberg matrix is not at all tridiagonal. When I perform the computation on the real part of `A` (so that `A == A.T`) then I do get a tridiagonal Hessenberg matrix, so there seems to be a problem with the imaginary components of `A`. Does anybody know why the Wikipedia code doesn't produce the expected results?

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import circulant


def arnoldi_iteration(A, b, n):
    m = A.shape[0]

    h = np.zeros((n + 1, n), dtype=np.complex)
    Q = np.zeros((m, n + 1), dtype=np.complex)

    q = b / np.linalg.norm(b)  # Normalize the input vector
    Q[:, 0] = q  # Use it as the first Krylov vector

    for k in range(n):
        v = A.dot(q)  # Generate a new candidate vector
        for j in range(k + 1):  # Subtract the projections on previous vectors
            h[j, k] = np.dot(Q[:, j], v)
            v = v - h[j, k] * Q[:, j]

        h[k + 1, k] = np.linalg.norm(v)
        eps = 1e-12  # If v is shorter than this threshold it is the zero vector
        if h[k + 1, k] > eps:  # Add the produced vector to the list, unless
            q = v / h[k + 1, k]  # the zero vector is produced.
            Q[:, k + 1] = q
        else:  # If that happens, stop iterating.
            return Q, h
    return Q, h


# Construct matrix A
N = 2**4
I = np.eye(N)
k = np.fft.fftfreq(N, 1.0 / N) + 0.5
alpha = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, N)*2e2
c = np.fft.fft(alpha) / N
C = circulant(c)
A = np.einsum("i, ij, j->ij", k, C, k)

# Show that A is Hermitian
print(np.allclose(A, A.conj().T))

# Arbitrary (random) initial vector
np.random.seed(0)
v = np.random.rand(N)
# Perform Arnoldi iteration with complex A
_, h = arnoldi_iteration(A, v, N)
# Perform Arnoldi iteration with real A
_, h2 = arnoldi_iteration(np.real(A), v, N)

# Plot results
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(np.abs(h))
plt.title("Complex A")
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(np.abs(h2))
plt.title("Real A")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After browsing through some conference presentation slides, I realised that at some point `Q` had to be conjugated when `A` is complex. The correct algorithm is posted below for reference, with the code change marked (note that this correction has also been submitted to the Wikipedia entry):

```
import numpy as np

def arnoldi_iteration(A, b, n):
    m = A.shape[0]

    h = np.zeros((n + 1, n), dtype=np.complex)
    Q = np.zeros((m, n + 1), dtype=np.complex)

    q = b / np.linalg.norm(b)
    Q[:, 0] = q

    for k in range(n):
        v = A.dot(q)
        for j in range(k + 1):
            h[j, k] = np.dot(Q[:, j].conj(), v)  # <-- Q needs conjugation!
            v = v - h[j, k] * Q[:, j]

        h[k + 1, k] = np.linalg.norm(v)
        eps = 1e-12
        if h[k + 1, k] > eps:
            q = v / h[k + 1, k]
            Q[:, k + 1] = q
        else:
            return Q, h
    return Q, h
```

Comment: Just curious how you get  v = v - h[j, k] * Q[:, j] working on numpy? I have v as a 2darray and h[j, k] * Q[:, j] as a 1d array...I had to do a lot of reshapes to make things like this work. How did you get around it?

Comment: @user1559897 `v` is supposed to be a 1D vector of size `m`. Make sure that your `b` is properly defined (which defines the size of `q`, which defines the size of `v = A.dot(q)`